# Jest global teardown runs before tests finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to make sure my app gets properly destroyed after all my Jest tests have run, but I'm running into some very strange behaviour trying to use Jest's global teardown config value.

Here's the situation: my app creates a database connection. It also has a `destroy` method that closes the database connection. This works.

I have a single test that starts the server, runs a query against the database connection. In my global teardown function, I call `app.destroy()`, but the process hangs.

If I comment out the `destroy` call in the global teardown function and put `app.destroy()` in my test after the query, Jest doesn't hang and closes like it's supposed to. I can also put `afterAll(() => app.destroy())` in my test file and things work properly.

Here is my `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'node'
  ],
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/src/testSetup.ts',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/src/testTeardown.ts'
};
```

Here is the test (it's currently the only test in the app):

```
import app from '../..';

describe('User router', () => {
  it('Should respond with an array of user objects', async () => {
    await app.models.User.query();
  });
});
```

And here is the global teardown in `<rootDir>/src/testTeardown.ts`:

```
import app from './index';

module.exports = async function testTeardown() {
  await app.destroy();
};
```

Using the code above, the process hangs after tests finish. I've tried adding a `console.log` to `testTeardown` and the end of the test, and the logs happen in the correct order: test logs, then teardown logs. However if I move `app.destroy()` into my test it works perfectly:

```
import app from '../..';

describe('User router', () => {
  it('Should respond with an array of user objects', async () => {
    await app.models.User.query();
    await app.destroy();
  });
});
```

This also works:

```
import app from '../..';

afterAll(() => app.destroy());

describe('User router', () => {
  it('Should respond with an array of user objects', async () => {
    await app.models.User.query();
  });
});
```

Why is this happening?

Also just for shits and giggles I tried setting a `global._app` in the test and then checking it in the teardown handler, but it was `undefined`. Do Jest's setup/teardown functions even get run in the same process as the tests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, jest globalSetup and globalTeardown files don't necessarily get run in the same process as your tests. This is because jest parallelises your tests and runs each test file in a separate process, but there is only one global setup/teardown phase for the combined set of test files.

You can use `setupFiles` to add a file that gets run in process with each test file.  In the `setupFiles` file you can put:

```
afterAll(() => app.destroy());
```

Your jest config is just

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'node'
  ],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/testSetup.ts']
};
```

Comment: P.S. You can pass `--runInBand` when you call jest to force your tests to run in the same process as your global setup/teardown, but I think jest will still create a "mock" environment for each test that is somewhat isolated.

Comment: I don't think `afterAll` is available in `setupFiles`. It likely should be `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of Jest just include this configuration option in your `jestconfiguration file`:

```
// globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests_setup/testSetup.ts',
// globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/tests_setup/testTearDown.ts',
setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/tests_setup/testSetup.ts',
    '<rootDir>/tests_setup/testTearDown.ts',
],
```

With this Jest will automatically load the `setup` and `tearDown` functions automatically
All you need to do is to export a function that sets up and runs the `beforeAll` and another that runs the `afterAll` i.e

`testSetup.ts`:

```
const setupTests = async () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        console.log('Test setup');

        mockMongoose.prepareStorage().then(() => {
            mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
            mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
                console.log('db connection is now open');
            });
        });
    });
};

export default setupTests;
```

and
`testTearDown.ts`:

```
const tearDownTests = async () => {
    afterAll(async () => {
        console.log('Finished on tests');

        await mongoose.disconnect();
        await mockMongoose.killMongo();
    });
};

export default tearDownTests;
```